# When a thread gets destroyed, why is the lock on an object still active?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I know that the destroy() method in Java is deprecated, but I just wanted to know if the thread holds a lock on the particular object after we call the destroy method for the thread. Destroying would terminate the thread so why is the lock on that object not released then?

When thread is dead, why does the object still remain locked?

Comment: Please add an example code snippet, how _you think_ a lock remains even though the thread terminated.

Comment: *When thread is dead, how the object is still remains locked?*  Because unlocking an object is an event that only the thread that holds the lock can do.  If that thread is destroyed, there's no thread that can unlock the lock, so it remains locked.  This just one reason why using `Thread.destroy()` is a bad idea.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Was there any provision/solution that whenever the destroy method has been called on a particular thread, release the lock held by that thread before getting terminated?

Comment: @Shelly I've never really dug into the specifics of forcibly killing a Java thread as it's inherently unreliable.  There's some wording in the `Thread.stop()` method about it:  *Stopping a thread with Thread.stop causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it has locked (as a natural consequence of the unchecked ThreadDeath exception propagating up the stack)*

Answer (score 4):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#destroy()) for the `Thread::destroy` (in Java 7) says this:

> Deprecated. This method was originally designed to destroy this thread without any cleanup. Any monitors it held would have remained locked. **However, the method was never implemented.** If it were to be implemented, it would be deadlock-prone in much the manner of suspend(). If the target thread held a lock protecting a critical system resource when it was destroyed, no thread could ever access this resource again. If another thread ever attempted to lock this resource, deadlock would result. Such deadlocks typically manifest themselves as "frozen" processes.

So, your question is moot.

The method was not implemented.  It is not possible to say *definitively* what behavior *would have been*.   Only what they originally intended it would be.

Having said that, the stated *intention* was that there would be no cleanup on `destroy()`, meaning:

- primitive locks acquired using `synchronized` would not have been released,
- `finally` blocks would not have been executed, and
- "resources" managed using `try` with resource would not have been closed.

---

The javadoc says that if you do call `destroy()` on a `Thread` the the behavior is to throw `NoSuchMethodError`.   Normal exception behavior will ensue.  Primitive locks will be released, and so on.

But ... just ... don't.

---

Finally, if you are talking about `Lock` objects instead of primitive locks,  these are only ever released if your code explicitly calls `Lock::unlock`.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) for `Lock` recommends that you lock and lock using `try ... finally` like this:

```
 Lock l = ...;
 l.lock();
 try {
     // access the resource protected by this lock
 } finally {
     l.unlock();
 }
```

... "in most cases".  If you consistently use this idiom, then you can be sure that any locks will always be released when a thread terminates.   (But that wouldn't have worked if `destroy()` had been implemented as envisaged.)

Comment: Note that the `NoSuchMethodError` would be thrown in the **calling** thread, not the target thread.

Answer (score 1):

In this example you can see lock is not released upon thread termination:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class CheckThreadLock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Lock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();

        Thread myThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+": myThread acquire lock");
                reentrantLock.lock();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+": Lock aquired: wait...");
                LockSupport.parkNanos(1_000_000_000);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+": Quiting thread");
            }
        };
        myThread.start();
        LockSupport.parkNanos(500_000_000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+": Acquire lock");
        reentrantLock.lock();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+"; Success!");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]: myThread acquire lock
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]: Lock aquired: wait...
Thread[main,5,main]: Acquire lock
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]: Quiting thread
//Success never happens because of deadlock
```